# Improve Spectrometer SNR

Tags: optics, visible-light, spectroscopy, noise

I am trying to perform optical emission spectroscopy but I have very low light intensity.
Without increasing the intensity, can I improve the SNR somehow? I am already close to the saturation point of my spectrometer and I have a signal intensity of around 1600 counts (from a max of 50000+ counts, it is saturated from noise when increasing integration time further). I have averaged my signal about 100 times which makes measurements last quite a bit.
Is it better to decrease integration time a bit in order to be able to increase averaging further, or keep integration time at its maximum? Plus does the time that an averaged measurement take (half an hour) increase the noise present due to changes in temperature, sunlight etc?

Comment: Is this an instrument or something you can modify.

Comment: There is an electronics stack exchange question that is similar.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/548034/signal-averaging-ccd  if you can modify the system and the ccd is not already cooled you can cool the ccd , but need to be careful of condensation.

Comment: It's a cmos detector and they dissipate less power, nevertheless temperatures are quite high where I live so yeah I might need some cooling but I dont think you can modify it.. Thank you very much! I will see that electronics question you refered me to. If you think of anythink else please tell me